# windows phone read sms function

Tags: windows-phone-8, sms

Want to ask does anyone know how to use the SmsInterceptor.SmsReceived event?
i want to use it in my school project only not going to publish it.

because in this thread mention we can ignore the exception
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/7dde1659-29e1-4ee9-ac6e-796b00c13cfc/

The project is to read the information from sms and convert it into graph and chart on the windows phone.

(i have an alternative idea also with using azure mobile service, but i don't know how to add data to database with computer system and how to connect GSM with the system)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SMS API is strictly available to OEMs. You can add both capabilities

`<Capability Name="ID_CAP_SMS_INTERCEPT_AGENT"/>`

and

`<Capability Name="ID_CAP_SMS_INTERCEPT_RECIPIENT"/>`

and use `SmsInterceptor` class in emulator but you can't deploy to devices.

Comment: Thank you,thought can bypass it in phone.
By the way, do you know any other method to read sms?